# Как записать неуправляемую dll в ресурсы приложения c#

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, компиляция, codedom

Работаю с компилятором `CodeDom`, нужно, чтобы в ресурсы приложения записалась неуправляемая dll, и ее можно было подключить наподобие LoadResource и вызвать нужные функции. Как это реализуется?

Прошу не предлагать решения с упаковщиками.

Comment: чем это отличается от добавления любого другого файла в ресурсы?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример вызова функции из добавленной в ресурсы dll.

Comment: [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/q/666799/312041), [два](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528178/Load-DLL-From-Embedded-Resource). Я просто загуглил [`c# dllimport from resource`](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+dllimport+from+resource)

Comment: Я вовсе не говорю про DllImport. Мне надо, чтобы dll не распаковывалась никуда, чтобы можно было обратиться к ней прямо через ресурсы (WinAPI).

Comment: _Мне надо, чтобы dll не распаковывалась никуда_ - скорей всего, это невозможно. Придётся распаковывать в файл.

Comment: То, что это возможно, я уверен, поскольку реализуется в компилируемых языках. Если в интернете про это ничего нет, значит никому еще не было нужно.